# Teenagers discover a network of tunnels to other times

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel, young-adult

I'm trying to identify a novel for young adults about travelling through time using a maze of time tunnels. I borrowed it from the Town Library in the early 1970's, so it may have been written during the late 50's or early 60's.

I think it's set in the North of England, possibly Newcastle. Two teenage lads fall through undergrowth into a large chamber. They can't climb out, and the only way is to walk through a tunnel at one end. It becomes a maze of tunnels with glowing walls, and when they reach the opening at the far end, they have travelled back to pre-history.

They walk back through the maze, and then through again, and come out at a different time. They repeat this exercise, and find that taking a different combination of left and right turns takes them to a different destination time.

I believe that, at one point, they were at 5,000 BC, and rescue a girl from being sacrificed.

Their final journey through is to take a lot of right hand turnings, so that they end up a long way in the future. The exit of the tunnel is manned, and the attendant tells them that "The last person to come through was a Roman soldier". They are then anathematized, and sent back to their own time.

Two years on, and there has been a power station built over the chamber, with the chamber itself housing the reactor.

If anyone can identify this book, I would be very grateful. I can then also buy a copy through Abebooks!

Comment: You get a point just for using the word "anathematized".

Comment: "anathematized" = "anaesthetised" ?

Comment: It was nearly 1 o'clock in the morning, and I couldn't remember how to spell "anaesthetised". So I left it to auto-correct!

Comment: Not quite the same meaning, though!

Comment: Came here to suggest the netflix show "Dark" only to find that apparently it's not the only thing that fits this description.

Comment: Came here to suggest the movie [_Time Trap_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Trap_(film)) (2017) only to find that apparently it's not the only thing that fits this description.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe this could be "[The Time Maze](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?423135)" by Reginald Maddock, published in 1960. Online information about this book seems really scanty - the [Goodreads page](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13364427-the-time-maze), for example, is disappointingly brief - so what I am writing is from memory, and may not be 100% accurate.

The story deals with two boys who fall into a cavern while exploring the woods near their home. The cavern leads into a maze, and by traversing the maze they can emerge at various points in history. I believe they go to the age of dinosaurs, to the neolithic era where they meet some cavemen, and eventually to the future. There they find a guardian-type figure, who prevents them entering (possibly by putting them to sleep - I don't recall).

I have not been able to find a good online summary of the book, but possibly the cover might jog the OP's memory.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Clara Diaz Sanchez!! I believe that you have answered my question - and within a few hours!
Currently, there are no copies on Abebooks, but at least I now know what I'm looking for. Thank you once again.

Comment: Glad to help @paul-horner. Maybe if you read it, you can post a fuller summary somewhere - the internet lacks one at the moment!